# Confused about steps_per_epoch and validation_steps in Keras

Tags: keras, tensorflow

According to the documentation in TF 2:

```
       steps_per_epoch: Integer or `None`.
            Total number of steps (batches of samples)
            before declaring one epoch finished and starting the
            next epoch. When training with input tensors such as
            TensorFlow data tensors, the default `None` is equal to
            the number of samples in your dataset divided by
            the batch size, or 1 if that cannot be determined. If x is a
            `tf.data` dataset, and 'steps_per_epoch'
            is None, the epoch will run until the input dataset is exhausted.
            This argument is not supported with array inputs.
        validation_steps: Only relevant if `validation_data` is provided and
            is a `tf.data` dataset. Total number of steps (batches of
            samples) to draw before stopping when performing validation
            at the end of every epoch. If validation_data is a `tf.data` dataset
            and 'validation_steps' is None, validation
            will run until the `validation_data` dataset is exhausted.
```

I don't understand this part:

```
Total number of steps (batches of samples)
                before declaring one epoch finished and starting the
                next epoch.
```

If I have 1000 samples, batch size = 100, then an epoch will take 10 steps to reach. Why is another steps_per_epoch is needed? If both are used, they are conflicting. Isn't it? If the batch size is 100, then 10 steps are needed. If also steps_per_epoch = 20, then it means in one epoch it needs 20 batches, which is conflicting with the '10' steps calculated through the batch size parameter 100.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

**There is an additional functionality with this method, way to think about it is a chance to use mini-epochs if loss stagnates too much**

Usually it is equal to `n_samples // batch_size`, **BUT**

`steps_per_epoch` give you the chance to feeding process of the NN when updating the learning rate using [`ReduceLROnPlateuau()`](https://keras.io/callbacks/#reducelronplateau). This callback checks the drop of the loss once each epoch has finished and if the loss has stagnated for a `patience` number of consecutive epochs, the callback decreases the learning rate to "slow-cook" the network. If your dataset is huge, as it is usually the case when you need to use generators, you would probably like to decay the learning rate within a single epoch (since it includes a big number of data). This can be achieved by setting `steps_per_epoch` to a value that is **less than** `n_samples // batch_size` without affecting the overall number of training epochs of your model.

Comment: In my example above, if batch size=100, and step_per_epoch=20, then overall epoch is still 10(1000/100), then in each epoch with 100 examples, the learning rate is possibly updated 5 times (100/20)? Similarly, apply this to the validation_steps, in each epoch, the model will be updated 5 times? But the documentation says "performing validation at the end of every epoch". So it seems no validation is performed within an epoch. Please help explain with this example and thanks.